# Distinguish between Desktop session and desktop environment

Tags: window-manager, desktop-environment, session, gdm

I heard/observed following words and want to distinguish information.

- Desktop Environment
- Desktop Session
- GDM Session
- Shell
- Window Manager

So **I can understand exact difference and working relation between them.**

Answer (score 3):

- A **desktop environment** (DE) is a combination of programs that define the interaction of the user and his applications.

  - Examples: Ubuntu's Unity, GNOME, KDE
- A **desktop session** is a running instance of a desktop environment.
- A GDM session is a session of the X display manager GDM (Gnome Display Manager), which mainly allows you to choose a desktop environment to run a desktop session.

  - Xdm is the X display manager that is part of the X distribution. Gdm and lightdm are newer variants.
  - An **X display manager** presents the graphical login screen, an can support to log in locally, or to remote hosts.
- The term "shell" is very generic, and mostly referring to interactive command line programs like bash - but I'm not sure that's what was meant in the question.
- A **window manager** is a program that handles location, size, visibility and other aspects of the windows used in a desktop session, so it is an important component of a desktop environment.

Comment: +1 Note that a window manager is not necessarily a component of a desktop environment.  *Some* of them may be used alone -- at which point it becomes apparent what a substantial part of the DE they are.  The WM is basically everything except the taskbar (and there are WM's that include taskbars and docks, meaning **the only distinguishing feature of a DE is an integrated filebrowser**).